# Menu(imageview) is not clickable in android

Tags: android, layout, widget, onclick, imageview

I have 4 activities in my app, which are the menu items, if i click on 1st activity's menu all the items gets displayed, but on the second or the preceeding activities menu is not clickable and also menu items are not getting displayed, had given same coding for all activities but still i'm not getting the result.
Here's my code for 2nd activity

```
public class About extends Activity {
LinearLayout line1, line2;
ImageView menu;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_about);
    line1=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ll1);
    line2=(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll2);

    menu=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.menu);

    menu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View v) {
   menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
      line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
  else { 
      line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
  } 
    }
});

          ImageView home = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.home);
          home.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Home.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView jobs = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.jobs);
           jobs.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Jobs.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView log = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.log);
          log.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, Login.class));
             }
              });

          ImageView about = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.about);
          about.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v){
                startActivity(new Intent(About.this, About.class));
             }
              });
```

xml code

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/black" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

      <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/menu"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/menu" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll2"
    android:layout_width="199dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/black" 
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ll1"
    android:visibility="gone"
    >


  <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/about"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/jobs"
    android:src="@drawable/about" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/jobs"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/jobs" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/log"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/log" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/home"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"

    android:src="@drawable/home" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to @Override the onClick Listener , just add @Override before the click listener

```
    @Override 
  public void onClick(View v) {
   menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  line1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  if (line2.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE || line2.getVisibility() == View.GONE) {
      line2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); } 
  else { 
      line2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); 
  } 
    }
});
```

Comment: The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method, m getting this error when i add Override @StyleMe

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to add a `super.onClick(v);` as a first line in your onCLick method?